# How to write undertext in alignment environment

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

Couldn't find as answer to this question in the site:
I want to write $A_i=\cap_{g\in G} gH_ig^{-1}$, But it shows me(in overleaf) this - [image]

While I want the $g\in G$ be **UNDER** the $\cap$.

Comment: No! I don't know why, but it does not work! @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: Did you try `$A_i=\bigcap\limits_{g\in G}gH_ig^{-1}$`?

Comment: Yes, thank you! I just tried using \cap didn't know that \bigcap was a thing. If you want you can write it as an answer, and Ill aprove it:)

Comment: note your title asks about align environment (which uses display math) but your example uses `$...$` which uses inline text style math so would use subscript position even with `\bigcap`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It just that I never knew that  \bigcap 
was a thing!